# Howt to create a shorthand for useDispatch with a specific action inside? Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I want to use `const dispatch = useAppDispatch()`

And then `dispatch(edit(xxxxxxx))`

I would like to have something like `const edit = useAppDispatch(edit(xxxxxxx))`

And then simply `edit(xxxxxxx)` in the code

But it doesn't work. ! help!

I get the error `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1`

Or I get the error  `React Hook "useAppDispatch" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function` if try to define a shorthand for useAppDispatch somewhere outside the function, which is what I want to do. Not to define it inside every component.

Comment: UseAppDispatch is a curried function. It means that it is a function which returns another function. Try useAppDispatch()(edit(xxxxxxx))

Comment: That's not correct, I'm afraid. It's _not_ "curried" - it's just a hook that returns the `store.dispatch` method for use in later click handlers.  The example you showed would end up calling `dispatch` _while rendering_, which is never correct behavior.

Comment: Thanks, that valuable info! But it still doesn't work. I get the same "must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function" error

Comment: @markerikson thank you for an explanation

Answer (score 1):

The right answer here is to create a function that dispatches when called:

```js
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
const handleClick = () => dispatch(edit(someArgument));
```

This *must* be declared inside the function component's body.

Comment: So... what you're saying is that I can't do what I want :dd

Comment: I'm not sure what else you're asking here. You can _never_ call a React hook outside the top level of a function component. Can you update your post to give more details on what else you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: well, if you're right, then I guess you answered my question, I'm just not happy :Dd